# C++ Visual Studio 2010 - Using Threads, Deque And Handlers

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, deque

I'm trying to use multiple threads in an application that reads out of a large file.

I want to read from the file in the main thread and put each line into a deque called `countedAddresses`.
The I want multiple threads to pick lines out of `countedAddresses` and pull all of the email addresses out of them and place them in a deque called `resolvedAddresses`.

At the moment this all works if there is only one `resolveAddressThread` running, but if I run two I get heap corruption errors.

I launch the threads with:

```
_beginthread( resolveAddressThread, 0, NULL );
_beginthread( resolveAddressThread, 0, NULL );
```

Here is the thread code:

```
unsigned int linesCounted, linesResolved, linesProcessed;
std::deque<std::string> countedAddresses;std::deque<std::string> resolvedAddresses;
HANDLE linesCMutex, linesRMutex, linesRCMutex;

void resolveAddressThread(void* pParams)
{ 
string fileLine= "";

while(1)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(linesCMutex, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(linesRCMutex, INFINITE);
    if (linesCounted>linesResolved)
    {

        if (countedAddresses.size()!=0)
        {
            fileLine = countedAddresses.front();
            countedAddresses.pop_front();
            ReleaseMutex(linesRCMutex);
            ReleaseMutex(linesCMutex);
        }
        else
        {
            ReleaseMutex(linesRCMutex);
            ReleaseMutex(linesCMutex);
            Sleep(1000);

        }
    }
    else
    { cout<<"All lines in the file have been processed."<<endl;
    ReleaseMutex(linesRCMutex);
    ReleaseMutex(linesCMutex);
    break;}


    if (fileLine.length()>1)
    {
        string::iterator strIter;
        string buffer;
        int tabCount=0;
        bool useFlag =false, keepFlag = false, stopFlag = false;
        buffer.clear();
        for(strIter=fileLine.begin(); strIter!=fileLine.end(); ++strIter)
        {
            if (*strIter == '\t')
            {
                ++tabCount;
            }
            if (tabCount == 10)
            {
                if ('\"'== *strIter)
                {
                    useFlag=!useFlag;
                }
                else if (useFlag && *strIter > 0)
                {

                    if (*strIter == '@')
                    {
                        buffer+=*strIter;
                        keepFlag = true;
                    }

                    else if ((*strIter ==' '||*strIter ==';')&& keepFlag)
                    {
                        if (buffer.at(buffer.length()-1)=='.')
                        {buffer = buffer.substr(0, buffer.length() - 1);}

                        WaitForSingleObject(linesRMutex, INFINITE);
                        resolvedAddresses.push_back(buffer);
                        ReleaseMutex(linesRMutex);
                        buffer.clear();
                        keepFlag = false;

                    }
                    else if (*strIter ==' '||*strIter ==';')
                    {
                        buffer.clear();
                        keepFlag = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buffer+=*strIter;
                    }

                }
            }
            if (tabCount ==11 && keepFlag==true)
            {
                if (buffer.at(buffer.length()-1)=='.')
                {buffer = buffer.substr(0, buffer.length() - 1);}

                WaitForSingleObject(linesRMutex, INFINITE);
                resolvedAddresses.push_back(buffer);
                ReleaseMutex(linesRMutex);
                buffer.clear();
                keepFlag = false;
            }
        }
        WaitForSingleObject(linesRCMutex, INFINITE);
        ++linesResolved;
        ReleaseMutex(linesRCMutex);
        fileLine.clear();
    }
}
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks,
ANkh

Comment: Firstly, independent of your error, I would replace that `while(1)...break` code with `while(linesCounted>linesResolved)`

Comment: I thought that too, but I couldn't figure out how to Mutex lock that.

Comment: Lots of problems with the code as presented.  `linesCounted` and `linesResolved` are not initialized.  Are these being modified by the original thread as these threads run?  Is `countedAddresses` being modified as these threads run?  That's the only explanation I can see for `linesCMutex`.

Comment: linesCounted is set to the number of lines in the file, linesResolved is initialized to 1 by the main thread before the resolveAddressThread is spawned.
countedAddresses has the lines from the file placed into it by the main thread.